# How to remove and return a custom object from ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, select, filter, lambda

I have an array of custom objects **Point**

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize x_coord, y_coord
    @x, @y = x_coord, y_coord
  end
end
```

I have an array of **Point** objects. I am wondering how I can delete from the array and return at the same time the point that has **point.x** equal to 5 ?

I tried like this:

```
array.delete(array.select {|point| point.x == 5})
```

where **array** is the container

Comment: what you want to return? array?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want to return a Point object. The one that has x = 5 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select) is returning an array, not a point.

So if there's only one point, or you care about the first match just do:

```
array.delete(array.select {|point| point.x == 5}.first )
```

Or even better as @Stefan says in comments:

```
array.delete(array.find { |point| point.x ==5 })
```

That involves the least change to your code.

I might also refactor so you can swap out the matching rule later:

```
def get_and_remove_point(array)
  array.delete match_in(array)
end

def match_in(array)
  array.find { |point| point.x == 5 }
end
```

Comment: [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) returns the first item.

Comment: right - i knew there was a find method but a quick google missed it - it's on enuberable not array - thanks - will update

Answer (score 0):

What **@Richard Jordan** said is correct, that is why you are not getting what you were looking for. But I would do as below using [`Array#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-index) and [`Array#delete_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) :

```
array.delete_at(array.index { |point| point.x == 5 })
```